# Where does cube root fall in growth order?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I am studying for an exam and going over growth order examples and I thought of an interesting problem.

Say I have the following list representing `big-O` run times.

> 3!,3,3n , n, log4n, n2, n3, n4, √n`square root`, ³√n `cubic root`

Now if I ordered these in least to greatest I'd do the following:

> 3 because constant 
>   log4n because logarithmic is slightly greater
>   √n **guessing here???**
>   ³√n **guessing here???**
>   n linear after that
>   3n linear + constant > linear
>   n^2 quadratic
>   n^3 cubic
>   n^4 4th power
>   3! factorial is always greatest

Is my placement of the roots correct? If not where would they go and why? This isn't a homework problem from the book. It's something I came up with to get clarification of placement of roots in growth order.

I emailed my instructor the same question and I am waiting on a response. Doing some research hasn't yielded me a concrete answer as to where a barebones simple root term would fall in terms of growth order.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: By sqrt(n)^3 `cubic root`, do you actually mean ³√n ?

Comment: @jxh yes I could not get the root symbol to paste over in here from ms-word. I don't know why.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question correctly from this incorrect formatting. Can you take a screen shot and post?

Comment: @jxh There isn't anything to screenshot. I did a different growth order problem as practice and thought what if I had a root term involved. How would my order changed. So I came up with the one above and asked my instructor and posted here.

Comment: There's no need to guess, it's very easy to figure this out simply from the definition of big-o.

Comment: @biziclop care to elaborate? I'd love to be able to not get tripped up on extra terms. Some advice on solving these types of problems would be cool to have.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) is the definition, so what you need to do is find a positive `M` for which the inequality holds. If you can prove there isn't any (which you usually do by assuming there is one and proving that for a large enough `n` the inequality will break), then one function grows faster than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `sqrt(n)` is between `log4n` and `n`.

Note square roots are `n^(1/2)` and cubic roots are `n^(1/3)`, so cubic roots are below square roots.

Also, `3!` is actually a constant because it doesn't depend on `n`.

Comment: Thank you so much! So in summation cubic roots or any roots above (say like a 4th or 5th root) lie after n. Should it be between `n` and `3n` or after `3n`? I'm thinking after 3n but just to be sure can you let me know?

Comment: Sorry, cubic roots are different, what you wrote was a different expression. Cubic roots are n^(1/3), so below sqrt(n).

Comment: sorry for the confusion. So they exist between log n and n then. It makes sense because they are making them smaller but not neccessarily smaller than log n. Thanks alot. I'll still accept the answer but you should update it since we had a miscommunication.

Answer (score 1):

roots are just inverted exponents,

sqrt(n) = n^(1/2)
cube_root(n) = n^(1/3)

technically the big O of (n) and (3n) are the same, because constants dont affect big O

Comment: But there are still some errors to correct.  3! goes to the beginning, and 3n+c=O(n).